# Read query params in Resolver class in Angular

Tags: angular

I want to get query param in resolver class to call service/api. Is it possible to read query params in resolver class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "resolver class"? Class implemening Resolve interface?

Comment: Yes. class Resolver  implements Resolve<any>{ ....}